# How do I link a specific string in one array to a second string in an other array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am at a complete loss by now.

I have tried countless times to get my program to work but it just doesn't want to.

Quick Overview:

I am currently programming a small vocabulary quiz which gives the user a random english term and the user has to answer with the correct german term.
After the quiz finishes, it will display the amount of correct/false answers.

Both the english and the german terms are stored in two-dimensional arrays and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to make sure that the correct german term is fixed to the corresponding english word.

Here's the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>


char eng[15][400]={"House","Lunatic","Nondescript","Ubiquity","Barley","Cardiac Arrest","Foreclosure",
"Thunderstorm","The answer to life, the universe and everything","Singularity"};
char ger[15][200]={"Haus","Irrer","nichtssagend","Allgegenwart","Gerste","Herzstillstand","Zwangsvollstreckung",
"Gewitter","42","Besonderheit"};
int i,corr=0,wrong=0,rnd, counter=0;
int choice[5];
int inArray;
char D[40];

int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) choice[i]=-1;

    while(counter < 5){
        rnd = rand()%10;
        inArray = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            if(choice[i] == rnd){
                inArray = 1;
            }
        }
        if(!inArray){
            printf("\nQuestion number %d : %s\nPlease enter your answer: ", counter, eng[rnd]);
            gets(D);

            if(D==ger[rnd]){
                corr++;
            }
            else{
                wrong++;
            }
            choice[counter] = rnd;
            counter++;  
        }
    }
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("\n\n\n# of correct answers: %d\n# of false answers: %d",corr,wrong);


return 0;
getchar();
}
```

Addendum: My counter for the # of answers correct/wrong seems to be broken as well, any ideas on that?

Comment: To answer the question in the title: the german word is at the same index in the `ger` array as the english word is in the `eng` array.

Comment: So I don't have to specifically link them anymore?

Comment: Correct, there's no need to link them. The arrays just need to be in the same order.

Comment: @user3386109 Okay, that's one headache gone. But it still says "# of false answers: 5" even though i put in the correct answers. Any insight on that?               Edit: btw, how can I upvote you? You're awesome :D

Comment: @Manny_Mar They actually are in the same order. The reason why they are not the same size is because i wanted to make sure that everything is in the arrays with nothing being cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with struct:

```
#include "stdio.h"

struct word {
    char *eng;
    char *ger;
};

struct word voc[] = {
    {"House", "Haus"},
    {"Lunatic", "Irrer"}
    //etc...
};

int main() {
    printf("%s %s\n", voc[1].eng, voc[1].ger);
    return 0;
}

// Lunatic Irrer
```

(use char pointer for static string)